# Is it possible to set a DatagramSocket to receive from any other IP-Address?

Tags: java, android

In my application, I have a `DatagramSocket`. I want to set the socket so that it will receive `DatagramPackets` from any IP-Address, and not have to specify one. Would this be possible at all?

I have a list of `EndPoints` I want to send data to at some point, and expect the messages sent to me to come from these addresses, but I don't want to iterate through this list and individually receive packets.

Is there any way I can achieve this? I've done some extensive searches, but I can't seem to find a suitable answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the default behavior of sockets, you shouldn't have to worry about being limited to any particular IP address. Don't `connect()` the socket, just call `receive()`.

Comment: But in `receive()`, you have to pass a `DatagramPacket`. Isn't it so that you have to specify an `IP-Address` when you create the packet?

Comment: @ThaMe90 - no.  Use this constructor to create a DatagramPacket for receiving a packet.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html#DatagramPacket(byte[],%20int)